# Could anyone please double-check the lyrics I transcribed for a song called "A La Playa"?

Tags: letras, letras-de-canciones

I recently found a gorgeous cumbia song called "A La Playa" by Aniceto Molina. The lyrics are not online, so I tried writing the lyrics down myself, but I can't make out a few of the words he is singing. Would anyone be able to double-check the lyrics that I wrote for this song?

The song is here: ["A La Playa" by Aniceto Molina](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dkieQMuLms)

And the lyrics I transcribed are as follows. I am most unsure about the part where he seems to say `Y tampoco de planes a risa se llena enamorado de ‘se panorama`; I know this is wrong, but I don't know what he is saying.

```
Contemplando la vista del mar
Ayer en Veracruz, me la pasaba
Contemplando la vista del mar
Ayer en Veracruz, me la pasaba
Acompañado de bella
Estaba con ella en la playa
Me iba bañar
Acompañado de bella
Estaba con ella en la playa
Me iba bañar

Yo me iba con Teresa (al orilla del mar)
Y bailábamos juntos (al orilla del mar)
Yo me iba con Rosa (al orilla del mar)
Y bailábamos juntos (al orilla del mar)

??? Y tampo contemplar esas risas se llena enamorado de ‘se panorama
??? Y tampoco de planes a risa se llena enamorado de ‘se panorama
A caminar por estar en la playa yo se ya encantando cumbia colombiana
A caminar por estar en la playa yo se ya encantando cumbia colombiana

Yo me iba con Teresa (al orilla del mar)
Y bailábamos juntos (al orilla del mar)
Yo me iba con Rosa (al orilla del mar)
Y bailábamos juntos (al orilla del mar)
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Bueno, y vuelve el sabor, de los sabaneros.

> Contemplando la brisa del mar. Allá en Veracruz, me la pasaba.(x2)

> Acompañado de bella estaba. Y con ella en la playa me iba a bañar.(x2)

> Yo me iba con Teresa/Rosa (a la orilla del mar) Y bailábamos juntos (a la orilla del mar) (x2)

> Y esa playa... es donde se baña.... Idaña Martinez.

> De tanto contemplar esa brisa seguía enamorado de ese panorama. (x2)

> (Y) al caminar por esas lindas playas yo seguía cantando cumbia colombiana. (x2)

> Yo me iba con Teresa/Rosa (a la orilla del mar) Y bailábamos juntos (a la orilla del mar) (x2)

hehe

Comment: Escuché la canción y si, está correcto

Comment: Wow, muchisimas gracias amigo! Siento bastante agradecido! Saludos!